# Netbeans Java jTable gives error message without selection

Tags: java, swing

I've got a jTable filled with data from a MySQL database. If the user selects a row and clicks onto a jButton, it shows up a jDialog, where she/he can edit all the data related to the selected row. It works perfectly, but the IDE gives an error message when there's no selection at all. What can I do?

The error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

My code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int username = 0;

    int un_row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String uname = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(un_row, username).toString();

    if(morethanzero()) {
        PersonalInfoEdit piedit = new PersonalInfoEdit(null, true, uname, perm);
        piedit.setLocationRelativeTo(piedit);
        piedit.setVisible(true); 
    }
}

boolean morethanzero(){
    if(model.getRowCount() < 0 || model.getColumnCount() < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There's no selected user!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jTable1.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you add more info about the error? Some part of the stacktrace not just the topmost line.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple, just take into account if no row has been selected. For example,

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int username = 0;

    int un_row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();

    if (un_row < 0) {
        return;    // if no row selected, get out!
    }       
    // .... rest of code here
```

Comment: Wow, it was really simple. Thank you so much!